# How do I compare two lists using iterators? c++

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

I'm stumped on my loop. When two lists sizes are equal, I want to compare the contents of it (string and int). I primarily don't understand this part:

> The content of all the containers in a BookList is the same - so pick one to walk. If the books are different, you have your answer

Here is my code:

```
int BookList::compare(const BookList& other) const {
  if (!containers_are_consistent() || !other.containers_are_consistent()) {
    throw BookList::InvalidInternalStateException(
        "Container consistency error in compare");
  }
   
// my implementation starts here
  auto begin_this_ = this->books_vector_.begin();
  auto begin_other_ = other.books_vector_.begin();

  auto end_this_ = this->books_vector_.end();
  auto end_other_ = other.books_vector_.end();


  if(this->size() == other.size()){
    while(begin_this_ != end_this_) {
      if(begin_this_ == begin_other_){
        ++begin_this_;
      } 
      return 0;
      
      if(begin_this_ != begin_other_) {
        //what do I do here?
      }
  }
    
    return  0;
  } else if(this->size() < other.size()){
    return -1;
  } else if(this->size() > other.size()){
    return  1;
  }
// ends here
}
```

Comment: You’ll need to move both iterators while “walking” through the list and keep doing it until the end. If you get to the end, or don’t get to the end, you’ll know the answer

Comment: question is, what is a BookList. Either iterators have unusual comparison semantic or that comparison is wrong

Comment: what is `BookList` ? It is not clear how one would compare two elements in the list from the code you posted. Typically it would be `*begin_this_ < *begin_other_` but not necessarily. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried using `std::equal` from the `<algorithm>` header?

Comment: If you are using `std::vector`, you can simply compare them with `==`: https://godbolt.org/z/77jTxKMMz

Comment: @mch And in C++20 you can three way compare them with `<=>`

Comment: And you can also compare them with `<` and `>` to get the `1` and `-1` return values: https://godbolt.org/z/65f35qY3T

Comment: Are you looking for a solution, or are you looking for help to build and understand a solution yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you probably want to compare the contents of the iterators and not the iterators themselves

```
if (*begin_this_ == *begin_other_) ...
```

Secondly, you return `0` whenever two iterators compare equal which means you exit the loop.

I suggest you return early only if two elements are NOT equal.

Sadly, you have not described what value is returned if the sizes are equal but the contents are not, so I will assume that the elements are `less than comparable`.

Then your while loop will look like

```
while (begin_this_ != end_this_) {
    if (*begin_this_ < *begin_other_)
        return -1;
    else if (*begin_other_ < *begin_this_)
        return 1;

   ++begin_this_;
   ++begin_other_;
}

// end of loop which means that all elements are equal
return 0;
```